# Request an URL don't want to wait till for that response

Tags: ssis-2008

I need to hit an URL but don't want to wait for response.. Just request an URL(cron) for updating data. I use this below code it wait till response comes. Please clarify.

```
string url = "http://exampleurl";
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: If you don't need a response why do you read it? (lines 3-5)

Comment: You can remove the last 2 lines, once you call `GetResponse()` the request to the URL is made and your cron will be triggered.

Comment: I tried with removing                                                                  
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string responseText = reader.ReadToEnd(); these two lines but it also wait till response comes.

Comment: You can try to put it in a thread so you don't need to wait [This can help you. ](https://www.dotnetperls.com/thread)

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming you don't need the response:*

This line wont let the program run the next line until the method has finished:

```
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

Therefore you could run that line as a seperate task to avoid the blocking of your code. Your code will continu to run even if the task ( getResponse() ) is not finished yet.

```
string url = "http://exampleurl";
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
var t = Task.Run(() => request.GetResponse() );
```

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx) for Task.Run() for a better understanding.

Edit:
if your running an old version of .net/c# task.run won't work, [you can use Task.Factory.StartNew instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38423472/what-is-the-difference-between-task-run-and-task-factory-startnew).

Comment: It seems error "Microsoft.sqlserver.Runtime.task does not contain a definition for run".

Comment: @Gnanaskandhan You should be using Namespace:   System.Threading.Tasks. See the documentation i linked which shows the namespace you need.

Comment: Added that too it seems same error "'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Task' 
does not contain a definition for 
'Run'".

Comment: @Gnanaskandhan could you try System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => request.GetResponse() );  Also which version number of c# do you use?

Comment: SSIS C# Script .. Im using 2008 R2

Comment: @Gnanaskandhan try my edited answer (with task.fanctory.startnew

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147455/discussion-between-sven-b-and-gnanaskandhan).