# how to assign Task return value to some variable in TPL C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, task-parallel-library

This is my `C#` function

```
public async Task GetAttendance(IEnumerable<Zone> zones)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (var zone in zones)
        {
            var req = new AttendeeRequestTO(zone.StartTime, zone.EndTime, zone.ZoneId.ToString(), accessToken);

            //THROWING COMPILE TIME ERROR
            zone.AttendanceCount = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _vClient.GetAttendeesCount(req));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Error

> Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task>' to 'int?'

**I don't want to apply await for each Task as each Task is independent & I want to each Task to run on its own context without waiting for any other Task.**

I mean 
 Task T1 - GO to API , get the value & set the count 
 Task T2 - GO to API , get the value & set the count 
 Task T3 - GO to API , get the value & set the count

T2 should not wait for T1 to complete, T3 should not wait for T2 to complete & so on.

How do I assign the value of each Task's output to `zone.AttendanceCount`?

Comment: You need to provide more information about your issue, What is the error you get ? What is the type of AttendanceCount ?

Comment: If you really need to use separate tasks(threads) for this, you could have a list of zone variables and as you iterate through the loop you assign values to each in asynch/await style..

Comment: @ZackISSOIR. error details added

Comment: Why are you using `async` if your code isn't asynchronous?

Comment: @ColinM, I am wondering what made you think so?

Comment: Where is your `await`?. Also can you attach the full exception message? There's a ">" where I assume you've trimmed the data type from `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int>`

Comment: You cannot store a Task<int> in a field of type int. You need to change your class design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to do asynchronous concurrency is to call each asynchronous method *without* using `await`, and then use `await Task.WhenAll`.

Since you have a collection and need a task for each one, you can call each asynchronous method using LINQ:

```
var tasks = zones.Select(async zone =>
{
  var req = new AttendeeRequestTO(zone.StartTime, zone.EndTime, zone.ZoneId.ToString(), accessToken);
  zone.AttendanceCount = await Task.Run(() => _vClient.GetAttendeesCount(req));
}).ToList();
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Note that I also [changed `StartNew` to `Run`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).

It would be better, if possible, to use a `GetAttendeesCountAsync` method on your client (assuming it's making an I/O call). If that method is available, you can avoid unnecessary use of the thread pool:

```
var tasks = zones.Select(async zone =>
{
  var req = new AttendeeRequestTO(zone.StartTime, zone.EndTime, zone.ZoneId.ToString(), accessToken);
  zone.AttendanceCount = await _vClient.GetAttendeesCountAsync(req);
}).ToList();
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: I like this Linq-based solution. The only thing that lacks here is exception handling.

Comment: Great. I just found a blog of yours https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html

Comment: @ZackISSOIR: Yes; the code as-is will handle exception(s) by only raising a single exception at the `await Task.WhenAll` line. If you prefer handling every exception individually, the easiest solution is to put a `try`/`catch` within the `Select` lambda.

Comment: @StephenCleary can you please take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55231438/is-it-possible-to-fire-3000-parallel-asynchronous-http-requests-from-asp-net-cor

Answer (score 0):

Task.Factory.StartNew returns a Task or a Task<T> so if you want to get the result returned by the async operation you should await it.

You just need to add await:

```
zone.AttendanceCount = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _vClient.GetAttendeesCount(req));
```

Note also that it is recommended to use Task.Run instead of Task.Factory.StartNew.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about the last sentence?  "_it is recommended to use Task.Run instead of Task.Factory.StartNew._"

Comment: @Unamed see this SO question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38423472/what-is-the-difference-between-task-run-and-task-factory-startnew