# Is it possible to fire 3000 parallel asynchronous HTTP requests from ASP.NET core Controller?

Tags: c#, azure, asynchronous, asp.net-core, task-parallel-library

I have a web API controller that receives a filter object from the front-end.

The filter basically is just a json array of objects that contains the filtering criteria.

Now based on that filter I have to run a query against an azure API (Azure log analytics api).

This is illustrated in this code snippet :

```
 var tasks = filters.Select(filter=>
            {
                try
                {
                    return service.GetPerformanceCounters(filter.SComputerId, filter.WorkSpace);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return Task.Run(() => new List<Metrics>());
                }
            })
            .ToList();

            var metrics = (await Task.WhenAll(tasks))
                                    .SelectMany(metric => metric)
                                    .ToList();
```

This basically means that if I have 3000 filter object I'll have to run 3000 asynchronous Parallel requests.

But when I was testing this code as I get to 100 filter object the asynchronous parallel tasks fail.

I get the following Exception in the debug panel :

> Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in Azure.DAL.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in Azure.DAL.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in Azure.DAL.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in Azure.DAL.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in Azure.DAL.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
>   The thread 0x3eac has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   The thread 0x2294 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   The thread 0x66b0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   The thread 0x6958 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   The thread 0xb5c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   The thread 0x6a98 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   The thread 0x16e8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   The thread 0x28f8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

How to make it possible to run more than 100 async HTTP request without having this problem, I have no control over the number of filters sent from the front but I need to be able to run a number of parallel async operation equivalent to the number of filters.

## Edit : Official requested endpoint doc included.

https://dev.loganalytics.io/documentation/Using-the-API/Limits

The doc states that:

> Using API key authentication to sample data, throttling rules are
>   applied per client IP address. Each client IP address is able to make
>   up to 200 requests per 30 seconds, with no cap on total calls per day.

### **Edit : GetPerformanceCounters implementation.**

```
        public async Task<List<Entities.Metrics>> GetPerformanceCounters(string sourceComputerId, string workspaceId)
    {

        Debug.WriteLine("New Task lauched");


        // The log analytics query 
          var query = $@"Perf 
        | where SourceComputerId == '{sourceComputerId}'
        | summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by SourceComputerId";




        var response = await RemoteKustoProvider.RunWorkSpaceQueryAsync
                  (
                        workspace: workspaceId,
                        query: query
                 );

        Debug.WriteLine("Task Finished");

        // Send query to the Kusto-Engine. 
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Entities.Metrics>>
        (
           response
       );
    }
```

Thanks in advance for helping me to solve this issue.

Comment: How does `service.GetPerformanceCounters` implementation look? If you wrap that in `Task.Run()` you can forget about 3000 concurrent requests.

Comment: @JohanP I edited the question, now it contains the implementation of GetPerformanceCounters method.

Comment: You could be facing timeout issues, which will cause exceptions to be thrown. You are blasting that service provider with 3000 simultaneous requests, maybe they're throttling you? This will cause exceptions. You need to inspect the exception more to see what's happening but from your code point of view, it all looks fine.

Comment: Not related to the question, but instead of  `return Task.Run(() => new List<Metrics>())` you can use `return Task.FromResult(new List<Metrics>())`, which avoids the overhead of creating a thread.

Comment: Not only the potential throttling by the Azure Service as this will look like a DoS attack to them (Azure Engineering protect their services against this), but also you could starve the ASP.Net Thread Pool, and if this kind of requests happen often most likely you are going to hit an ephemeral port exhaustion problem, but probably you are not getting that far in the 'issues stack' yet, as by default ASP.Net EndPoint Manager is configured to Max 10 connections to the same domain (if I recall properly) what most likely is happening is you are having timeouts in your HttpRequests.

Comment: @JesusSalas OP's code is async, so there won't be a threadpool starvation issue, it isn't synchronously blocking waiting for the result. The .net core `MaxConnectionsPerServer` is set to int max by default, so 3000 outgoing connections won't be a problem. Port exhaustion _could_ be a problem under high load if the client is disposed after every request but quite unlikely in this scenario.

Comment: So this design is not good? is there any other approach to deal with this? can you advise me another design to make the program work .

Comment: @JesusSalas I included the service endpoint documentation, they are saying that you can make up to 200 requests in 30 seconds.

Comment: @JohanP please see the doc link that I included.

Comment: @JohanP As far as I know in ASP.Net Core SynchronizationContext was deprecated and causes async/await operations under the same request context to have implicit parallelism, this was a change from 'legacy' ASP.Net for several reasons (including performance) where only one thread was allowed to do work on each request context (including continuations). ASP.Net Core await defaults to the thread pool context and asynchronous continuations may run on any thread, and they may all run in parallel. Taking this in account OP's code may starve the ThreadPool if too many continuations happen at once.

Comment: @JesusSalas the threadpool consists of  2 pools; worker threads and IO threads. When you are hitting the endpoint, that is served by a worker thread. When the async network call is encountered, it is given to the network driver to do its thing. When the data finally arrives, it is posted to an IOCP, which is essentially a queue of completed items. This is then served by a thread from the IO pool and can process thousands of items. The only starvation I can see is if you are just doing CPU bound work that blocks and you have very high scale, which isn't the case here.

Comment: @JohanP OP didn't specify the expected workload for the API, you are inferring this, while might be possible 'high scale' is not explicit, there are potential situations that could cause a similar effect, specially in distributed systems, if unconstrained, there is a good chance it will go wild at some point. The risk of queuing thread requests is there, what could lead to an unresponsive system. The key here is 'parallel work', OP's must constraint the number of parallel tasks (async or not) to avoid this risk. 'Hope' is not a tool in architecture design dynamics at all.

Comment: @JesusSalas Let me restate what I meant. Even if OP was hitting tremendous load, the code AS IS will be able to handle it because it is all pure IO work. However, making that many http requests under load will have some part of the system fail, it could be throttling, it could be port exhausting, it could be socket exceptions but the one thing that will NOT be the issue, is threadpool starvation. You can test this for yourself, spin up a controller and hit it with 3k requests in an async way. If the code was CPU bound and BLOCKING, it WILL lead to starvation.

Answer (score 0):

There's a *number* of issues here. First and foremost, you need to realize that all active work requires a thread. Those threads come from the thread pool, which is generally set to 1000 out of the box. That means right from the start, you're exhausting the thread pool with that many tasks, so likely 2000 of them are being queued. Async *helps*, but it's not magic. Some of the threads may end up returning the to the pool once the request goes out, but thread switches are not guaranteed. Regardless, you're still draining the thread pool faster than you can fill it.

Then, it's not clear what's *actually* happening here, because there's multiple layers and you're spoon-feeding us a layer at a time. You posted what `GetPerformanceCounters` does, but now it's not clear what `RemoteKustoProvider.RunWorkSpaceQueryAsync` does. At some point, you're using something like `HttpClient`, though, in order to eventually make the request to Azure. Depending on how you're doing that (and frankly, based on the quality of this code, I have no great hope you're doing it correctly), you're likely also exhausting the connection pool. That's a far more constricted resource, so that means your throughput is drastically reduced, causing further back up down the chain.

Next, even if you *could* just blast out all 3000 requests at once, that essentially amounts to a DDoS attack on the recipient server. I wouldn't be surprised at all if you're actually being throttled or outright blocked by firewalls on the other end. That then of course - you guessed it - bottlenecks everything else down the line as well.

Finally, even if all this function as you intended, firing off 3000 tasks is not the same thing as "parallel processing". For that you'd need to utilize the `Parallel` class from the TPL.

I'm not sure what you're ultimate goal is here, but there's surely a more efficient way to do it that sending 3000 separate requests. If there truly is not, then you need to batch them - sending a few a time over a longer period. The whole process should be moved off to an external process, and should be merely scheduled by your web application. You can then use something like SignalR to push updates and eventually the result back down to the user when it all completes.

Comment: Basically RemoteKustoProvider is just a wrapper around this azure SDK https://dev.loganalytics.io/documentation/Tools/CSharp-Sdk , and RunWorkSpaceQueryAsync just calls the Query method of their OperationalInsightsDataClient SDK class.  Please help to solve this problem if you have a better way or better design kindly feel free to tell me what I can change.

Comment: Well, it looks like that supports a query language syntax, so more likely than not, you should simply a way to get all this in a single query (and a single request).