# how to wait for multiple async tasks in c#?

Tags: c#

I have this shared function  :

```
        public static async Task<IList<T>> ExecuteQueryAsync<T>(this CloudTable table, TableQuery<T> query, System.Threading.CancellationToken ct = default(System.Threading.CancellationToken), Action<IList<T>> onProgress = null) where T : ITableEntity, new()
    {

        var items = new List<T>();
        TableContinuationToken token = null;

        do
        {

            TableQuerySegment<T> seg = await table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync<T>(query, token);
            token = seg.ContinuationToken;
            items.AddRange(seg);
            if (onProgress != null) onProgress(items);

        } while (token != null && !ct.IsCancellationRequested);

        return items;
    }
```

I normally would call this function like this

```
var query = new TableQuery<DynamicTableEntity>();
var res2 = await myTable.ExecuteQueryAsync(query);
```

which gives me IList

I'm trying to execute two simultaneous queries, but I'm very confused.

What I did so far

```
                List<Task> TaskList = new List<Task>();
                Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
                {
                    return  table1.ExecuteQueryAsync(query);
                });


                Task task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
                {
                    return  table2.ExecuteQueryAsync(query2);
                });

                Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);

                var res = ((Task<Task<IList<DynamicTableEntity>>>)task1).Result.Result ;

                var res2 = ((Task<Task<IList<DynamicTableEntity>>>)task2).Result.Result ;
```

It runs fine, but I'm not sure if it is the right approach ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use `Task.Factory.StartNew` (nor would the [better `Task.Run`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38423472/what-is-the-difference-between-task-run-and-task-factory-startnew) needed either), and you shouldn't use `Task.WaitAll` for asynchronous code.

Instead, ensure the method is marked as `async`, then just start the tasks, without awaiting, and then use await the result of `Task.WhenAll`

```
 var task1 = table1.ExecuteQueryAsync(query);
 var task2 = table2.ExecuteQueryAsync(query2);

 await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);

 // Access the results of the completed Tasks here
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Task.WhenAll()` you can await the result, avoiding `.Result.Result`. For example:

```cs
Task task1 = table1.ExecuteQueryAsync(query);

Task task2 = table2.ExecuteQueryAsync(query2);

var result = await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);

var res = result[0];
var res2 = result[1];
```

Comment: You can avoid `.Result.Result` also with `WaitAll`. The difference by using `WhenAll` is only that it the waiting is asynchronous.

Comment: thanks guys ! much appreciated !! learning something new today

Comment: @GregaMohorko Good point, my mistake.