# await without FromCurrentSynchronizationContext?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, async-await, task

As I know using `async/await` is equivalent for `Task.Run` with `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`. But I faced with embarrassment when try this (Xamarin.Forms environment):

```
Action ReFocus = async () =>
{
    // not work well as next somehow
    adresseeEntry.Unfocus();
    await Task.Run(() => {});
    adresseeEntry.Focus();
};
ReFocus();
```

This doesn't work like the following code:

```
Action ReFocus = () =>
{
    adresseeEntry.Unfocus();
    Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() => true).ContinueWith(r =>
    {
        adresseeEntry.Focus();
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());//*/
};
ReFocus();
```

Maybe on focusing an element is not a very good example. But this is a real situation that I encountered in practice (in the first case, the focus does not happen for some reason).

Comment: It should be the same. What are you finding different?

Comment: Is this all your code or you have omitted something? Is there any `ConfigureAwait(false)` after some previous `await`?

Comment: Fire-and-forget code is dangerous.  If the async code fails with an exception then you'll never see it.

Comment: @PauloMorgado, in the first case, there is no element focus, like in the second case

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, nop. In my code never used the `ConfigureAwait` method

Comment: @HansPassant, this probably seems to be true. I have already encountered the fact that in parallel threads, Xamarin does not handle my errors, but only completes the execution of threads . At the same time, the program runs on as if nothing had happened. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Is there anything you miss out in the post? These two piece of code snippet just works the same on my side. Refer to earlier post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38423472/what-is-the-difference-between-task-run-and-task-factory-startnew, answer by Mykhailo Seniutovych, there's still some difference between these two usages.