# Why is there a difference in behaviour between Task.Run and Task.Factory.StartNew?

Tags: c#, async-await, task

From what I've read, I thought `Task.Run` was the same as `Task.Factory.StartNew`. With `Task.Run` just a newer and preferred way of doing things. However, I'm seeing a slight difference in behaviour with the following code.

I've created a simple .Net 6 console app.

Worker.cs has the content:

```cs
internal class Worker
{
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient = new();

    public async Task StartTaskRun(CancellationToken token)
    {
        await Task.Run(async () => await SomeWork(token));
    }

    public async Task StartTaskFactory(CancellationToken token)
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await SomeWork(token));
    }

    private async Task SomeWork(CancellationToken token)
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var result = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://www.yahoo.com", token);
                await Task.Delay(5000, token);
            }
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task has been canceled");
        }
    }
}
```

And Program.cs has the content:

```cs
var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

var worker = new Worker();

//worker.StartTaskFactory(cancellationTokenSource.Token); // 1# Returns
//worker.StartTaskRun(cancellationTokenSource.Token); // 2# Returns

//await worker.StartTaskFactory(cancellationTokenSource.Token); // 3# Returns
//await worker.StartTaskRun(cancellationTokenSource.Token); // #4 Does not return

Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
Console.ReadLine();

cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

Console.WriteLine("Cancelling");
Console.ReadLine();
```

In Program.cs, I have 4 different ways that I call the Start methods. The #1 and #2 calls work as intended. They make a fire and forget call to the async methods and the console shows the "Hello World" output and continues with the logic.

However, why does #3 and #4 differ in results? #3 continues execution in the same way as #1 and #2. However, #4 seems to continue to wait on the StartTaskRun() call?

Can anyone explain the difference in results on this please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Task.Run() and Task.Factory.StartNew()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38423472/what-is-the-difference-between-task-run-and-task-factory-startnew)

Comment: `Task.Run` has overloads designed to work correctly with `async` lambdas. `TaskFactory.StartNew` does not. You can't just assume they'll work the same without considering if you're calling "similar" overloads of both.

Comment: @MonkeyDLuffy As good as those answers are, I canot actually spot the answer to this question anywhere in there

Comment: The difference is that `Task.Run` has an overload which takes a `Func<Task>`, whereas `TaskFactory.StartNew` only has overloads which take an `Action`. Therefore if you pass an `async () => await ...` to `TaskTFactory`, it gets turned into an `async void` method, which means that `TaskFactory` has no way of knowing when the operation started by the delegate actually completes

Comment: In `SomeWork()` you are not checking the cancellationToken so unless `GetStringAsync` and `Task.Delay` call `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` or throw an exception themselves, you will be in an endless loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple rules are:

- `Task.Factory.StartNew` existed before `async`-`await`.
- `Task.Run` was introduced with `async`-`await`.
- You should **REALLY** know when you need to use `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

  - And it's almost never.

    - For most developers it will be "never in a lifetime".
- If you are not sure, **ALWAYS** use `Task.Run`.